# Continuous integration using TFS

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, alm

I am heavily used to using SVN/Git coupled with Teamcity to do Continuous Integration & Delivery. Pretty easy there to create MSBuild / NANt scripts to do what I want. Recently for work purpose I am placed in a project where I am trying to set TFS up to do the same but gosh a clear cut doco seems to be unavailable there (or I am too used to Teamcity).

Will you be able to point me to the right direction re

- TFS build server best practices
- Creating zipped artifacts and persisting them (build def settings doesn't seem to work in my case for some reason)
- Deploying the artifacts in different environments

Comment: you can point a standard builddef at a msbuild proj and if you use the build extensions you can use a nant script: https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/workitem/11423. 
You could also link TFS to a teamcity build server if you wanted, teamcity supports TFS.

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate TFS with all kinds of tooling but if you want to use all TFS offers you, you can use the following:

- A Build Definition for your project that uses one of your build servers. This Build Definition can be configured to run as a CI build and store the build output on the TFS server. This output can then be downloaded as a zip file through the web portal.
- For deployment, [Microsoft Release Management](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/release-management-vs.aspx) is the recommended tooling. RM can be tied to your build (using a special Release Management template that stores the build output in a shared folder on your server).

Combining CI builds with Release Management gives you a nice solution for continuous deployment through all kinds of environments

Another option is by using [Lab Management.](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/explore/lab-management-vs.aspx) This is well suited for deploying and managing test environments, both physical and virtual.

When it comes to best practices for TFS I would love to point you to all the `[guidance we created as ALM Rangers.](http://aka.ms/vsarsolutions) Here you will find guidance on installing, configuring and running TFS in all kinds of scenarios including Build servers and DevOps automatic deployment scenarios.

Comment: The default build template can drop binaries as well. The thing that the RM template enables is triggering a release from a build and handling shifting tokenized config files around